# find my iphone application

Tags: find-my-iphone

My find my iphone was being used, not by myself. It could be my ex. Is there a way to see where that person used the find my iphone to figure out where i am? Maybe narrow it down to a certain State that someone had logged into, to use the find my iphone locator

Answer (score 1):

Find my iPhone works with iCloud id, as explain [here](http://answersfactory.com/how-to-use-find-my-iphone/), So if you are using same iCloud ID and she knows the password then she can trace you, Its better to change your iCloud ID or at least change its password.

Or you can disable the location services to disable tracking by going in *Setting > Privacy > Location Services*

Comment: will this work if a my phone gets blacklisted? Also how to trace after its battery is dead or the person found my phone switches it off or switches internet off?